# How to install and run electrum wallet with Python3 on server?

Tags: python-3.x, centos, payment, bitcoin, wallet

I'm implementing bitcoin wallet for the first time, so i don't have much knowledge on this thing.

But by following electrum official [documentation](https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) , i have tried to install electrum on my macbook and it worked well, now i want to install same on my server running centOS. but installation command `python3 run_electrum` throws this error

> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
>   This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
>
> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

Is there anything i'm missing here, i'm using python 3.6.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok instead of running electrum direct i've tried to install electrum with this command

> python3 -m pip install Electrum-3.3.8.tar.gz

then

> sudo ln -s ~/.local/bin/electrum /usr/local/bin/electrum

after this now i am able to use `electrum` command on my server, i've also successfully created wallet now

Also remember that you can run electrum from any folder you choose, following the alternative instructions from electrum:

`tar -xvf Electrum-3.3.8.tar.gz
python3 Electrum-3.3.8/run_electrum`

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use AppImage from official website. Download it in some place of your server and run without installation:

```
$ chmod +x electrum-3.3.8-x86_64.AppImage  # make it executable at first
$ ./electrum-3.3.8-x86_64.AppImage daemon start
```